# Stackoverflow API - get “received” upvote count of a user.

Tags: discussion, feature-request, api

I'm currently using the Stackoverflow API to get a list of detailed user information (via http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/users-by-ids). There is an attribute called "up_vote_count" which returns the number of how often a user has GIVEN upvotes. What I want is some kind of the opposite:

Is it possible with the Stackoverflow API to get/calculate the count of how often a user RECEIVE upvotes?

The only way I would see is to crawl through the reputation changes via http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-reputation-changes and add +1 to a local upvote variable if there is "+10 reputation". But this would suck pretty hard...

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why would doing it that way be so terrible?

Answer (score 2):

You could call all of the various ways a user can be upvoted and get how many upvotes they received for each.

- [Questions](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-questions)
- [Answers](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-answers)
- [Comments](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-comments)

Within each enumerate looking for the number of upvotes (or score in Comments case).

Comment: That would be far more complicated than polling the reputation changes route.

Comment: @George Edison: But would give more accurate results, and I assumed given the comparision to total up votes given that an overall number is needed, which doesn't seem to be possible in the reputation route from what I can tell.

Comment: Why don't you think it's possible to obtain all votes received using the reputation route?

Comment: @George Edison: Because the API says so"Reputation changes are intentionally scrubbed of some data to make it difficult to correlate votes on particular posts with user reputation changes. That being said, this method returns enough data for reasonable display of reputation trends." Additionally my Stackoverflow account with returns 9 results when I use the console, which is a bit less than what I have received upvotes for.

Comment: Hmmm... well hopefully @Kevin will be able to tell us what data is scrubbed and maybe explain the anomalies in the reputation method.